# Regex to match a non numeric value or end of string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match date formats with regex.  An example date of each is:

```
02 Apr 15
02 Apr 2015
```

The regex I'm using to match the first one is:

```
re.compile("([0-9]{2}) ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) ([0-9]{2})")
```

And for the second:

```
re.compile("([0-9]{2}) ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) ([0-9]{4})")
```

Now the issue I'm having is that the second date will match the first regex, even though it contains 4 digits rather than just 2.  I wanted to add an end of line to the regex, but sometimes there is the time appended to it (I.e. 4:32).  So what I want to do is have the first regex match the corresponding date with the possibility of having nothing after it or a space+stuff after it.  So the first one should match:

```
"02 Apr 15"
"02 Apr 15 5:23"
```

but not match:

```
"02 Apr 2015"
"02 Apr 2015 5:23"
```

It should be flopped for the other regex.  So, pretty much, the only values that are important are the first 3 (dd Mmm YY and dd Mmm YYYY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is word boundary i.e.:

```
re.compile("\\b([0-9]{2}) ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) ([0-9]{2})\\b")
```

This will make sure 4 digit year is not matched while trying to matching first date in your examples.

However you should consider [Python date parse routine](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2)

Comment: awesome! I'll add the regex code in right now since it follows a lot of how the script is written.  I'll definitely look more into the parsing, though; if it'll make the script better, I'll do it.